# Linux Mint - Facebook font rendering in Chrome is ugly

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, firefox, chrome

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1 x64 Cinnamon. The fonts in Facebook look really ugly in Google Chrome. Firefox has no issues with it though. Here's a comparison:

- Fonts in Google Chrome - Notice how the height seems flattened...

[image: Fonts in Google Chrome - Notice how the height seems flattened...]

- Fonts in Firefox - They look much better.

[image: Fonts in Firefox - They look much better.]

How do I fix the font rendering in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this issue is caused by Chrome not being able to replace the Helvetica font with the proper alternate font when the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package is installed in the machine. I solved the issue by completely removing the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package using the following command:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

A restart after running the above command, the fonts came back neat and cool again.